# Google ImportXML to Scrape Prices off TIAA.org

Tags: xpath, web-scraping, google-sheets

A number of investments from TIAA.org are not traded on exchanges and not available via a ticker symbol thru say GoogleFinance etc. For one of these I would like to 'scrape' the daily price directly off of TIAA.org website and into a cell auto-magically.

In Google sheets I thought it would be easy enough using ImportHTML as a table but no luck. I've experimented with ImportXML but cannot seem to figure out how to set the xpath query for the specific price I'm interested in and leaving me confused - keep ending up with a "N/A" cell ("Error: Imported content is empty").

Using this URL:

https://www.tiaa.org/public/investment-performance/tiaavariableannuity/profile?ticker=41091375

Could someone take a look and suggest how I might import the daily price (aka unit value) for QREARX into a Google sheet cell using an xpath with ImportXML or other method?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you slightly change your url prefix to `https://www.tiaa.org/public/tcfpi/Investment/Portfolio?symbol=` and then add your ticket number at the end like you did in your example: `41091375`

then you can use this importxml function to pull in the value your looking for:

```
=IMPORTXML("https://www.tiaa.org/public/tcfpi/Investment/Portfolio?symbol=41091375","//*[@class='first']/text()")
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately it looks like since this was posted that they may have redesigned their site somewhat rendering that modified URL obsolete.